# Is it normal to have android errors in flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I just started learning flutter yesterday and it seems all good except for when I try pushing my application to GitHub I am met with a handful of errors. Although when I run "main.dart" it runs perfectly fine in the emulator. I can't seem to find any docs or solutions on as to why this is and the purpose behind this. I notice that all these errors are derived from the Android source files and not ios related folders. For my android project structure, my project SDK is currently Android Studio's default JDK.[image]

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but I also had faced android studio showing errors when running Flutter project. but its running fine with emulator and real device. so I just leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with your android folder. Actually Android SDK is currently set for the flutter(flutter environment). This is why it is not finding the Android part correct. You can right click on the Android folder and can open with Android in new Android studio window.