# Android Files Showing Error when pushing to github

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cross-platform

whenever I tried to push the code to GitHub. The Android code block in the flutter app is showing 28 errors in 10 files. But with the same code if I launch the app in abd it is working fine.

I have tried changing the project structure. Doing the suggestion given by the IDE.

I'm using Android Studio - Dolphin IDE

Comment: It's totally fine, because your IDE environment is not set for Android development in that project (which is a Flutter project). No need to worry about

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal to have android errors in flutter project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984403/is-it-normal-to-have-android-errors-in-flutter-project)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.